# MPI Program not running on my pc, how to run it properly?

Tags: mpi, mpich

My sample code is here. why m getting this error??
I have searched it one said that its due to one of the processor crash. how to run it??
Any guide me please??

```
#include <mpi.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // Get the name of the processor
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);

    // Print off a hello world message
    printf("Hello world from processor %s, rank %d out of %d processors\n",
           processor_name, world_rank, world_size);

    // Finalize the MPI environment.
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

[image: at cmd]
[image: at mpich2 executor]

Comment: Are running in the same host or across different hosts?

Comment: at the same host

Comment: Strange I could not reproduced it, which version are using

Comment: mpich2-1.4 but not working fine.

Comment: MPICH dropped support for windows after the version 1.4 . So the latest version won't work on windows.